# FLASK - Show result from API call on same render page

Tags: python, python-requests

The response text from my API call shows in the logs but how can I display one of the values from the output. For example the below returns the result.

```
{"uuid":"FqDSDSVJY+GYAHSTSGA=","id":6238236373}
```

I am wanting to render "6238236373" on my index.html page. What is the best option to convert to valid json objects and then call these objects onto my page?

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/alert', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def alert():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)
     
    if request.method == 'GET': 
    
        import requests

        url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/v1"

        payload="{}"
        headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        }

        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

        print(response.text)
    
    return render_template('index.html', form=form,)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>

{ render id response }

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that you're sending and receiving data in json format, I think you could use `json` to transform the `result.text` into a dictionary.

```
import json
#...
data = json.loads(response.text)
#...
print(data['id']) # should output 6238236373
```

More info about `json` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).